# What is the distribution of the following random variables, where the inputs are $N(0,1)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, independence, chi-squared

$X$ and $Y$ are independent $N(0,1)$ random variables: What is the distribution, of $$\frac{2XY}{\sqrt{X^{2}+Y^{2}}}?$$ I know the numerator is a difference of two independent $\chi^2$ random variables, and the denominator is a $\chi_{n=2}$ distributed random variable, but I don't know how to calculate the distribution of the ratio.

If $X=\left(X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{n}\right)$ is a random vector with $X_i\sim N(0,1)$ independent coordinates, than what is the distribution of $Y_{1}=\frac{X}{\left\Vert X\right\Vert }$ and $Y_{2}=\left\Vert X\right\Vert ^{2}$ where the norm is the eucledian norm? Are they ($Y_1$ and $Y_2$ ) independent?

I think $Y_1$ has some kind of $t$-distribution, and $Y_2$ has some kind of $\chi^2_n$ distribution, and I dont think they are independent, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Your first question is answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2647442/321264. The second question has also been asked before, so please search the site.

Comment: Thank you...I tried but I didn't find it, I will check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use polar coordinates $X = R \cos(\Theta)$, $Y = R \sin(\Theta)$, $R \ge 0$, $0 \le \Theta \le 2\pi$.  Then $R$ and $\Theta$ are independent with $R$ having density $f_R(r) = r e^{-r^2/2}$ and $\Theta$ uniform in $[0,2\pi]$.  Your random variable is 
$$ V = 2 R \sin(\Theta)\cos(\Theta) = R \sin(2\Theta)$$
I don't know if there's a nice formula for the PDF or CDF of $V$, but for the MGF I get
$$ \mathbb E [\exp(sV)] = \frac{e^{s^2/2}}{4} \left(1 + \text{erf}(s/\sqrt{2})\right)$$

EDIT: This is wrong, see comments.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. Doesn't $R\sin(2\Theta)$ have the same distribution as $R\sin(\Theta)$ as you said something similar in this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/503304/321264? So the mgf is incorrect?

Comment: Oh, of course, good observation.  Yes, of course, the MGF should be $e^{s^2/2}$.  I don't know how I got that answer.