# Finding pdfs of $\frac1{X^2}$ and $\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac1{X^2}+\frac1{W^2}\right)$ where $X,W$ are independent $N(0,1)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, density-function

$X,W$ are independent random variables, both $N(0,1)$, i.e. $f_X(x)=f_W(x)= \frac{1}{{\sqrt{2\pi}}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$.

1. Find PDF of $Y:=\frac{1}{X^2}$
2. Find PDF of $\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{X^2}+\frac{1}{W^2}\right)$

For the first case $a)$ I have:

\begin{eqnarray*}
 F_Y(y)=P(Y \leq y)=P(\frac{1}{X^2}\leq y) \:=
\end{eqnarray*}

## \begin{Bmatrix}P(\frac{1}{X^2}\leq y) \: y<0
 & \\ P(\frac{1}{X^2} \leq y), \: y>0
 & 
\end{Bmatrix}

\begin{Bmatrix} 0,  \: y<0
 & \\ P(\frac{1}{X^2} \geq y), \: y>0
 & 
\end{Bmatrix}
$$ P(X^2 \geq \frac{1}{y})= P(X \leq -\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} \cup X\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}})=$$
$$ = P(X\leq -\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}) + 1 - P(X\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}))= $$
$$= F_X(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}) +1 - F_X(\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}) $$

we have therefore:

$$ F_Y(y)= \left\{\begin{matrix}F_X(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}) +1 - F_X(\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}), \: y>0
 & \\ 0, \: y<0
 & 
\end{matrix}\right. $$

for $y>0$ we have:

$$ f_Y(y) = f_X(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}))*(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}))´ - f_X(\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}))*(\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}))´ $$
$$ = f_X(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}))*\frac{y^{\frac{-3}{2}}}{2} - f_X(\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}))*(-\frac{y^{\frac{-3}{2}}}{2})$$
$$ =\frac{y^{\frac{-3}{2}}}{2}*(f_X(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}})) - f_X(\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}))) $$
$$ = \frac{1}{2} * y^{\frac{-3}{2}}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}e^{-\frac{1}{2y}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}e^{-\frac{1}{2y}}) =  y^{\frac{-3}{2}}*\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}*e^{-\frac{1}{2y}}$$

For the second part, there is a hint that we should use polar coordinates and that the substitution $t=\cot(2 \theta)$ could be helpful. 
So since we have the PDF of both X and W (if what I have in (a) is correct), I tried using the convolution formula and calculating the integral, but I haven't been very successful, so I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: Why do you think deleting the question after an answer has been posted is okay? I invested time into this question, so the least you can do to avoid being rude is to do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Your work for the first problem is correct.

Let $\Phi(\cdot)$ and $\phi(\cdot)$ be the cdf and pdf of standard normal distribution, as usual.

Since $X$ is standard normal, you have for every $y>0$,

$$P\left(\frac1{X^2}\le y\right)=\cdots=1-\Phi\left(\frac1{\sqrt y}\right)+\Phi\left(-\frac1{\sqrt y}\right)=2\left(1-\Phi\left(\frac1{\sqrt y}\right)\right)$$

So the pdf of $Y=\frac1{X^2}$ must be

$$f_Y(y)=\frac1{y^{3/2}}\phi\left(\frac1{\sqrt y}\right)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}y^{3/2}}e^{-1/2y}\mathbf1_{y>0}$$

You can also use change of variables to directly say

\begin{align}
f_Y(y)&=\phi\left(\frac1{\sqrt y}\right)\left|\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}\left(\frac1{\sqrt y}\right)\right|+\phi\left(\frac{-1}{\sqrt y}\right)\left|\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}\left(\frac{-1}{\sqrt y}\right)\right|
\\&=2\phi\left(\frac1{\sqrt y}\right)\left|\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}\left(\frac1{\sqrt y}\right)\right|
\\&=\frac1{y^{3/2}}\phi\left(\frac1{\sqrt y}\right)
\end{align}

For the second problem, transform to polar coordinates $(X,W)\mapsto (R,\Theta)$ such that $X=R\cos\Theta$ and $W=R\sin\Theta$. Then

$$Z=\frac14\left(\frac1{X^2}+\frac1{W^2}\right)=\frac{X^2+W^2}{4X^2W^2}=\frac1{(R\sin(2\Theta))^2}$$

All you have to do now is [show that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2647462/321264) $R\sin(2\Theta)$ also has a standard normal distribution, so that $$Z\stackrel{d}=\frac1{X^2}=Y$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!
Is the last step supposed to be done by transforming random variables? Because one usually takes two random variables, I'm not sure what the other one would be in this case. Maybe I got it wrong. Or should I transform X and W into polar coordinates with $2 \theta$ ?

Comment: As I have mentioned in the linked post, you can transform $(R,\Theta)\mapsto (R\sin(2\Theta),R\cos(2\Theta))$. Or you can [argue](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/503304/321264) that $\sin(2\Theta)$ has the same distribution as $\sin(\Theta)$ where $\Theta\sim U(0,2\pi)$, so that $R\sin(2\Theta)$ has the same distribution as $R\sin(\Theta)=W$.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to this transformation method since it was never officially introduced in the lectures, I fail to understand what I am supposed to do with this transformation? To get a joint pdf and then to calculate a marginal pdf by integrating this joint pdf? I would really appreciate some hints, I am completely lost.

Comment: Please read my first comment. To reiterate, you can show that $R\sin(2\Theta)$ has the same distribution as $W\sim N(0,1)$ without actually finding the joint density of the transformed variables using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/503304/321264) argument. If you haven't been introduced to transformations, it is better not to go down that path. You only know the cdf method, is that correct?

Comment: Well, there were some exercises where we had to use transformations, but the one you linked was far too complicated for me to understand. This second argument is also OK, but I think something more formal is expected of us. So I could basically use some transformation, but not in this way as linked.

Comment: The second argument is not any less formal. This is not a one-to-one transformation, so maybe you haven't come across that before. Otherwise if you know two-variable transformations, the process is exactly the same. If you intend to derive the joint density using a polar change of variables, then the method in my linked answer is what you would have to go through. The process is highlighted in detail there.